# Self referential associations (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I want to create a system for users to comment on posts where comments can also have replies.  Since I can't do a self-referential HABTM relationship, I did some research and saw that I should be going about it in this manner:

```
Post
  has_many :comments
end

Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :replies, :class_name => 'Comment'
end
```

I know this isn't 100% correct (which is why I'm asking).  If anyone could advise me on how to set up this sort of relationship and how I would need to create the migrations, I'd appreciate it!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to this is to just use the [acts_as_tree](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree) plugin. It's pretty easy to see how it's implemented, but basically you need to add a self-referential `belongs_to` as well as a `parent_id` column on your model. (A comment with a nil parent_id is a top-level comment; not a reply.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is also possible to reply to a reply, you would be having a tree of comments. Therefore I suggest you use [`acts_as_tree`](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree):

```
Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  acts_as_tree :order => 'created_at'
end
```